# Do depth or amount of water affect the lifting force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Lifting force depends on the volume in water and the density of water.

Is there any possibility that depth or amount of water can affect the force, in real life conditions?

Comment: Please clarify. Are you talking about lifting an object submerged in water?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any possibility that depth or amount of water can affect the
>   force, in real life conditions?

As you said, the lifting force depends on the volume of the displaced water and the density of the water. So, if the volume of a submerged body does not change, but the density of the water does, the lifting force should change as well.

Can density change under real life conditions?

Although water does not compress much, only about $46ppm$ per $1 atm$ of pressure, it adds up. Assuming sea water density of $1025kg/m^3$, the pressure increase at $4000m$ depth will be $\rho gh=1025*9.8*4000=40180000 Pa$ or about $396 atm$, which translates to $46\times10^{-6}\times396=0.018$ or $1.8\%$ shrinkage of volume or $1.8\%$ increase in density (thanks to Rafik Fayzulin for pointing the significance of that factor).

In addition, water density is affected by temperature and salinity: it decreases with temperature and increases with salinity.

The picture below (copied form [this article](http://www.iupui.edu/~g115/mod07/lecture08.html)) shows a typical curve of density vs depth in an ocean:

[image]

The article explains how temperature and salinity affect density at different depth zones.

So, the density of the water does change with depth and therefore the lifting force will change, too.

Comment: this graph does not reflect the increasing density of water due to compression, at the depth of 4000m the density reaches 1.046 g/cm3,  water compressability is about 46 ppm/1 atm  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/compress.html

Comment: @RafikFayzulin Thanks a lot for pointing that out  - what I called insignificant turns out to be more significant than other factors. I've added these numbers to the answer.